# Why kinetic friction does not depend on speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, speed

I was studying friction and got that [kinetic friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Kinetic_friction) is directly proportional to the normal reaction and hence:

$\text{Force of kinetic friction=coefficient of kinetic friction $\times$ normal reaction}$.

I don't see speed anywhere. If kinetic friction has no relation with speed then why fast running racing car's tyre abrade too early than normal cars??

Comment: This Question is probably answered in this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2408/

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2408/